# "Basket of Deplorables"

Tags: expressions, adjectives, nominalizations

I never heard of the idiom "basket of deplorables" and did´t find it anywhere.. could someone explain it?

The meaning of deplorable according to my dictionary (as adjective):
deserving strong condemnation; completely unacceptable; shockingly bad in quality.

My thesaurus lists two kinds of synonyms: (1) in the meaning of disgraceful (and also, as one of many, hateful) and (2) in the meaning of lamentable.

The context of this quote is a speech, where H. Clinton described Trump supporters.

Is the described group characterised as lamentable/disgracful, the included persons or is it meant more as a description of the groups behaviour (lamenting in a hateful/disgraceful way)?

Which synonyms would be most suitable in the given context?

Thank in advance! Best regards!

Comment: It's not what one would consider an "idiom".

Comment: It's not an idiom. 'Basket' is a metaphor like a 'bunch'. 'Deplorables' is the use of an adjective as a collective noun.

Comment: You might find the following Language Log article to be useful: ["Horribles and deplorables"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=28057)

Comment: I would really like to know where she got those baskets.  Did she write that speech herself, or is there someone she can fire?

Comment: Idiom was definitely the wrong term, thanks. What I thought to read between the lines was, that she might wanted to say that those people are angry and hateful people. Nonetheless it`s still an insult, the accentuation would be slightly different. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @Mitch, that's really the answer to this question. If you wouldn't mind posting it as such, it could be accepted and the question removed from "unanswered" lists...

Answer (score 3):

It's not an idiom (meaning not inferable from the parts) or a set phrase (a special phrase that people have used often, usually literal or obvious metaphor but has more to it). It is a new turn of phrase putting two things together that are not common or common together so it stands out.

'Basket' is used as a metaphor/metonymy of 'grouping', like 'a bunch'. 'Deplorables' is the use of an adjective (an attribute) as a collective noun (the defining sense of the group) which is a small synecdoche (in English).

The vague disparagement of the phrase comes from a few things:

- 'Basket', an everyday object (though not particular common these days given technology) evokes some faint connections with phrases that are somewhat disparaging like "bag of hair". The most common uses of the words are in proverbs/sayings like "Don't put all your eggs in one basket" and "Going to hell in a hand basket"
- 'Deplorable' is one of many fancy words terrible. It can act a little euphemistically because the word is educated and therefore unclear in informal contexts.
- 'Basket' and 'deplorable' come from very contrasting registers. 'Basket' is somewhat pedestrian, everyday, humble. 'Deplorable' is erudite, high-brow.
- The phrase has the pattern of a 'group of things' which has the subtle distancing and objectification like 'the X' instead of just 'X'. It even evokes [terms of venery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal) like 'pack of dogs', and even more like the humorous made up ones like 'murder of crows'

But that is a semantic, connotative analysis. The real controversy is the political context.